# Проблема с запуском приложения FastAPI из-за router папки

Tags: python, post, sqlalchemy, fastapi, router

Когда я захожу в свой проект и пишу в консоль
'uvicorn src.main:app --reload',
то мой проект запускается и дается ссылка, но сама страница просто не загружается и все из-за этого куска кода:

```
@router.post("/")
async def add_specific_operations(new_operation:OperationCreate, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    stmt = insert(operation).values(**new_operation.dict())
    await session.execute(stmt)
    await session.commit()
    return {"status": "success"}
```

Я поменял `dict` на `model_dump`:

```
stmt = insert(operation).values(**new_operation.model_dump())
```

и страница отвисла.
Но когда я перезапускаю Pycharm, я сталкиваюсь с той же самой проблемой  - опять запускаю проект и опять не грузиться.

Но стоит мне поменять в той же строке `model_dump` на `dict`:

```
stmt = insert(operation).values(**new_operation.dict())
```

все начинает заново работать, но каждый раз после перезапуска Pycharm мне приходиться менять dict и model_dump, а потом наоборот, чтобы моя страница отвисла.

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы не менять эти методы каждый раз?

Comment: посмотрите что вы передаете этой функции в new_operation во всех местах